# C - malloc and automatic storage

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I understand that variables declared within a function have [automatic storage](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Automatic_variable). Does this mean it's not necessary to `free` pointers (`p` below) that have been explicitly allocated within a function call using `malloc`?

```
void f() {
  int *p;

  p = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *p = 1;
  printf("%p %d\n", p, *p);  // 0x7fc135c02850 1
  free(p);                   // is this necessary?
}

int main() {
  f();
}
```

(Note that I used a pointer to an `int` here, but the question applies to any pointer that's a return value of `malloc` and friends.)

I'm guessing no, since `malloc` allocates memory on the heap and not the stack; thus the memory `p` points to won't automatically be deallocated when the stack frame for `f()` is popped.

Comment: You’re freeing the memory pointed to by the pointer the variable contains, not the variable.

Comment: Thanks, edited the question; let me know if you have a better suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` itself is automatic storage, and it will disappear when the function ends. What it *points to* however does need to be `free()'d`, at some point. For example, you could return the `malloc()'d` memory from the function, and `free()` it later on - `p` has still disappeared

Comment: Could you explain your last sentence a bit more?

Comment: Your function could (in theory) do `return p;` (as long as the return type matched). Then, as long as you store the result when you call it - `int *r = f();`, for example - you can `free` the memory later on - `free (r);` - despite the fact that `p` itself no longer exists.

Comment: I'm using this as the accepted answer instead of https://stackoverflow.com/a/47319825/2419669 since this arrived first. But both are the same in terms of content.

Answer (score 3):

The memory you allocate with `malloc()` needs to be `free()`'d. In your case, automatic storage applies to the variable `p` itself, but not to the memory you allocated! When you use `free(p)`, you free the memory `p` *points to* and not the `p` variable *itself*.

Comment: Would it be possible to `free` the region of memory pointed to by `p`in `f()` after `f()` is off the stack?

Comment: Of course! As Steve explained, if you return your pointer `p`, you can `free()` it later as it is allocated in the heap, not the stack. The `malloc()`'d memory isn't automatically `free()`'d when you exit the scope of the function where it was `malloc()`'d.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, a call to `free` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask for memory allocate manually, you must free manually the space you asked for. So free is necessary there